# Angular material table - sort direction not reading in screen reader

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I am working on the accessibility. I checked the Angular documentation and it's not reading sort direction. Here is the [link](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview)

I did some research and found out that we have to do below to change it. Here is the reference [link](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview#accessibility).
***The aria-label for the sort button can be set in MatSortHeaderIntl.***

I am trying to set this value but it's failing with below error. Can someone help me with this error. Here is the [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqlqud-wc9ntc).

---

```
Type '"one"' is not assignable to type '(id: string, direction: SortDirection) => string'.
(property) MatSortHeaderIntl.sortDescriptionLabel: (id: string, direction: SortDirection) => string
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify your constructor as follows:

```
constructor( private matSortService:MatSortHeaderIntl) {
    this.sortedData = this.desserts.slice();
    this.matSortService.sortDescriptionLabel = (id: string, direction: SortDirection) => { 
        return `Sorted by ${id} ${direction == 'asc' ? 'ascending' : 'descending'}`; 
    }
}
```

This will add a `span` containing the text returned by the function defined in the constructor. The span has the class `cdk-visually-hidden` so it is [visible to screen readers](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview#hiding-elements-while-keeping-them-available-for-screen-readers).

Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqlqud-hxazdj?file=app/sort-overview-example.ts) for a demo. If you sort by the `Carbs` column and then inspect the `th` for that column you should see the following:

```
<th _ngcontent-c24="" mat-sort-header="carbs" class="ng-tns-c25-3 mat-sort-header-sorted" ng-reflect-id="carbs">
    <div class="mat-sort-header-container">
    ...
    </div>
    <span class="cdk-visually-hidden ng-tns-c25-3 ng-star-inserted">&nbsp;Sorted by carbs ascending</span>
</th>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But still it's not reading the direction(ascending or descending) of the sort. Is this feature not supported by Angular Material table?

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood the question. I've updated the answer to show how to include the column and direction of the sort